# cakephp form helper for a date: how to make minYear and maxYear work

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to implement a date selector in Cake-1.3. The problem I'm having is that I've not been able to confine the year selector to the desired set of years, which is 2012 through the current year, whatever that might be. I've tried 3 or 4 ways of coding this, based on my own thoughts and on examples from the cakephp site, Stack Overflow, and at least one other site. No matter which approach I take, the years in the selection list range from 1994 to 2034.

Here is the current version of the code for this:

```
echo "<div class='date'>" . $this->Form->input('start_date', 
    array('type'=>'date',
        'default'=>array('month'=>$yesterday['month'],
        'day'=>$yesterday['mday'],
        'year' => $today['year'],
         array('dateFormat' => 'MDY', 'minYear' => 2012, 'maxYear' => $yesterday['year'],
          selected)
        )
    )
) . "</div>";
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your input options should all be in a single unnested array.

```
echo "<div class='date'>" . $this->Form->input('start_date', 
    array('type'=>'date',
        'default'=>array('month'=>$yesterday['month'],
         'day'=>$yesterday['mday'],
         'year' => $today['year']),
         'dateFormat' => 'MDY', 
         'minYear' => 2012, 
         'maxYear' => $yesterday['year']
    )
)
. "</div>";
```

Comment: This insight was good but the code didn't work. There is a missing ')' after the default for year, to close off the default value.

Comment: @user3758031  Thanks, updated my answer.  I have such a hard time having all the proper closing parens on SO, since I'm used to working with ide's that do that for you.  XD